# libpng - crash due to memory error [iOS & Android]

Tags: ios, android-ndk, heap-memory, libpng, memory-corruption

I'm using libpng version 1.6.15 in both my iOS and Android-NDK project to read .png image and use it for OpenGL ES 2.0 texture. I have configured libpng without errors, below is the code where I read PNG image:

```
uint8_t  *outputData;
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");

png_structp png = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if(!png) abort();

png_infop info = png_create_info_struct(png);
if(!info) abort();

if(setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png))) abort();

png_init_io(png, fp);

png_read_info(png, info);

width      = png_get_image_width(png, info);
height     = png_get_image_height(png, info);
color_type = png_get_color_type(png, info);
bit_depth  = png_get_bit_depth(png, info);

texWidth = width;
texHeight = height;

if(bit_depth == 16)
    png_set_strip_16(png);

if(color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE)
    png_set_palette_to_rgb(png);

if(color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY && bit_depth < 8)
    png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8(png);

if(png_get_valid(png, info, PNG_INFO_tRNS))
    png_set_tRNS_to_alpha(png);

if(color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB ||
   color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY ||
   color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE)
    png_set_filler(png, 0xFF, PNG_FILLER_AFTER);


if(color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY ||
   color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY_ALPHA)
    png_set_gray_to_rgb(png);

png_read_update_info(png, info);
unsigned  long row_bytes = png_get_rowbytes(png,info);
outputData = (uint8_t*) malloc(row_bytes * height * 4); // Allocating memory

row_pointers = (png_bytep*)malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * height);
for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    row_pointers[y] = (png_byte*)malloc(png_get_rowbytes(png,info));
}
png_read_image(png, row_pointers);
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    //memcpy(outputData+(row_bytes * (height-1-i)), row_pointers[i], row_bytes);
    memcpy(outputData+(row_bytes * i), row_pointers[i], row_bytes);
}
printf("Allocating memory ... ");
//png_destroy_info_struct(png, &info);
//free(row_pointers);
fclose(fp);

return  outputData;
```

And after that I'm using the output data returned for setting texture as below:

```
glGenTextures(1, &OGLTextureName);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, OGLTextureName);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,getOGLTextureFormat(format), width, height, 0, getOGLTextureFormat(format), getOGLTextureType(texelType), outputData);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
free(outputData);
```

It is working sometimes in Android-NDK project, reading the images correctly so that texture is perfect, but most of the time app is getting crashed after reading the data with the message as below:

in iOS:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x16884844: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

in Android

```
heap corruption detected by dlfree
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have also tried setting breakpoint in `malloc_error_break` but that is not helping me. Is that the issue due to chunks in images?

Comment: You're not checking the malloc() for success (outputData != NULL, row_pointers[y] != NULL).  Your outputData array is four times as large as it needs to be (rowbytes is already width*4).

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Thank you for the response. I have made the change and verified whether memory allocated for those objects, Still the same issue.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson 
Sorry , I found the issue, it is with the filename , char[ ] was not properly allocated while calling. Fixed it. Working great. Thank you again.